# Multi step Angular Form - Updating ngModel in hidden steps

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a multi-step form and each step is required to have an save draft feature. This save draft is not working because some fields are not yet selected in some other fields of the form. When I press save draft I supposed to **send all the fields for all steps**.

I initialized these fields using `[(ngModel)]` but I don't understand why the initialization is happening only when the step of those filed its active. I created a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-step-reactive-form-hukvke).

So, in `multi-step-form.component.ts` we have `selectedInputValue: string = 'Input value test'` that its used for all inputs in `multi=step-form.component.html` line 44 `[(ngModel)]="selectedInputValue"`. You can see in the step 1 the values are preselected, but if you go in the step 3 you can see the input its not initialized. You can play with (next/ preview) buttons and look in the json. The value its in the input but not in my json (`formData`).

My question is, how I can fix this pre-selection for the fields that are hidden in other steps? I want for example to pre-select some some dropdowns values.

Comment: if you use ReactiveForms, NOT use [(ngModel)] to give value to the "input" ((yeah, remove the [(ngModel)], use setValue or pathValue or give value when you create the form

Comment: @Eliseo I'm using this command only to select the values in some dropdowns. I'm using [this component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v7.2.6-lts/#/dropdown) with reactive forms. I created a fast demo giving the example of input. I will update the main subject to be more precise.